# node.js - Caching handlebars.js using service worker

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I want to ask about service workers. I made a web application and try to implement services worker. I'm using `.hbs` for my views layout and when I cache static files I can't cache the `.hbs`, `.css` and `.js` files.

- `public/`

  - `css/`

    - `style.css`
  - `js/`

    - `app.js`
  - `manifest.json`
  - `service-worker.js`
- `views/`

  - `home.hbs`
  - `partial/`

    - `header.hbs`
      *`footer.hbs`

When I deploy my app it fails to cache the `home.hbs`, `style.css` and my `app.js` file; I cant access my web offline.

What should I do to fix it?

This is my `app.js`:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./service-worker.js', { scope: './service-worker.js' })
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.log("Service Worker Registered");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
    })

}

var get = function(url) {   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var result = xhr.responseText
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                reject(xhr);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();

  });  };
```

This is my service worker:

```
var cacheName = 'v1'; var cacheFiles = [    './login',   './css/styles.css',    './js/app.js',   ]; self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Installed');

    // e.waitUntil Delays the event until the Promise is resolved
    e.waitUntil(

        // Open the cache
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

            // Add all the default files to the cache           console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching cacheFiles');          return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
        })  ); // end e.waitUntil });


self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activated');

    e.waitUntil(

        // Get all the cache keys (cacheName)       caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {           return Promise.all(cacheNames.map(function(thisCacheName) {

                // If a cached item is saved under a previous cacheName
                if (thisCacheName !== cacheName) {

                    // Delete that cached file
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing Cached Files from Cache - ', thisCacheName);
                    return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
                }           }));        })  ); // end e.waitUntil

});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);

    // e.respondWidth Responds to the fetch event   e.respondWith(

        // Check in cache for the request being made        caches.match(e.request)


            .then(function(response) {

                // If the request is in the cache
                if ( response ) {
                    console.log("[ServiceWorker] Found in Cache", e.request.url, response);
                    // Return the cached version
                    return response;
                }

                // If the request is NOT in the cache, fetch and cache

                var requestClone = e.request.clone();
                fetch(requestClone)
                    .then(function(response) {

                        if ( !response ) {
                            console.log("[ServiceWorker] No response from fetch ")
                            return response;
                        }

                        var responseClone = response.clone();

                        //  Open the cache
                        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

                            // Put the fetched response in the cache
                            cache.put(e.request, responseClone);
                            console.log('[ServiceWorker] New Data Cached', e.request.url);

                            // Return the response
                            return response;

                        }); // end caches.open

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Error Fetching & Caching New Data', err);
                    });


            }) // end caches.match(e.request)   ); // end e.respondWith });
```

What should I do so I can cache the `.hbs` file?

Comment: Please read about [how to format your question using Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Blockquotes (`>`) are _not_ for code blocks, or for lists. Please use appropriate markup.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call the .hbs the same way you would call them on your app router.

If you have in your router :

```
router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});
```

then in your service worker you can cache it like:

```
var filesToCache = [
'/home',
'css/style.css',
'js/app.js'
];
```

No dot before js, and you mispelled 'style'.
Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Your service worker code is really bad. I hope there is a typo, but the `cache.addAll()` funciton is commented out!

Anyway, I will give this a try...

```
var cacheName ='v2';
var filesToCache = [
'/',
'public/css/style.css',
'js/app.js',
'views/home.hbs',
];


self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    }).then(function() {
        return self.skipWaiting();
    })
  );
});
...
...
```

Comment: hi @fabio Marzocca
thank you so much for the answer. i try to make a new question. and its more clearer there. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778465/node-js-how-caching-handlebars-js-using-service-worker

i try your code and fix it. but all the file is 404 not found error.. im not sure what should i do.

Comment: Im not an expert, but maybe the service worker wont save the ".hbs" in the cache because those files never get to the clients. The ".hbs" extention is there to indicate handlebars wich files need to be rendered before send the final ".html" file to the client.
The problem that you are facing is that you are trying to cache content that is dynamicaly created by the server.
A possible solution could be the following: first try to save the rendered ".html" response that handlebars give in the first req. Then try to cache either in memory, redis, client-side using service worker, etc.