# node.js - how Caching handlebars.js using service worker

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, google-cloud-platform, service-worker

I want to ask about service workers. I made a web application and try to implement services worker. I'm using .hbs for my views layout and when I cache static files I can't cache the .hbs, .css and .js files.

this is how i save my file:

```
public/
 css/
   style.css
  js/
   app.js
  manifest.json
  service-worker.js
views/
  home.hbs
  partial/
   header.hbs
```

When I deploy my app it fails to cache the home.hbs, style.css and my app.js file; I cant access my web offline.

What should I do to fix it?

This is my app.js :

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./service-worker.js', { scope: './service-worker.js' })
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.log("Service Worker Registered");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
  console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
   })

}

var get = function(url) {   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var result = xhr.responseText
            result = JSON.parse(result);
            resolve(result);
        } else {
            reject(xhr);
        }
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();

  });  };
```

this is my service-worker.js

```
var cacheName = 'v1';
var cacheFiles = [
    './',
    './home',
    './login',
'./welcome',
'./register',
'./css/styles.css',
'./js/app.js',
'./images/fb-logo.png',
'./images/g-logo.png',
'./images/t-logo.png',
'./images/logofix.png',
'./images/icon192.png',
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js',
'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',
'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700',
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'

];
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Installed');

// e.waitUntil Delays the event until the Promise is resolved
e.waitUntil(

    // Open the cache
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

        // Add all the default files to the cache
        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching cacheFiles');
        return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
    })
); // end e.waitUntil
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activated');

e.waitUntil(

    // Get all the cache keys (cacheName)
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(cacheNames.map(function(thisCacheName) {

            // If a cached item is saved under a previous cacheName
            if (thisCacheName !== cacheName) {

                // Delete that cached file
                console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing Cached Files from Cache - ', thisCacheName);
                return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
            }
        }));
    })
); // end e.waitUntil

});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);

// e.respondWidth Responds to the fetch event
e.respondWith(

    // Check in cache for the request being made
    caches.match(e.request)


        .then(function(response) {

            // If the request is in the cache
            if ( response ) {
                console.log("[ServiceWorker] Found in Cache", e.request.url, response);
                // Return the cached version
                return response;
            }

            // If the request is NOT in the cache, fetch and cache

            var requestClone = e.request.clone();
            fetch(requestClone)
                .then(function(response) {

                    if ( !response ) {
                        console.log("[ServiceWorker] No response from fetch ")
                        return response;
                    }

                    var responseClone = response.clone();

                    //  Open the cache
                    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

                        // Put the fetched response in the cache
                        cache.put(e.request, responseClone);
                        console.log('[ServiceWorker] New Data Cached',     e.request.url);

                        // Return the response
                        return response;

                    }); // end caches.open

                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Error Fetching & Caching New Data', err);
                });


        }) // end caches.match(e.request)
); // end e.respondWith
});
```

What should I do so I can cache the .hbs file?
thank you

Comment: What exactly happens in terms of "fails to cache the home.hbs, style.css and my app.js file"? How do you know it fails?

Comment: Hi! @GauntFace thank you so much the answer. when i cached home.hbs, style.css and app.js file the status is not 200. the status is 304. like this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzsmISVHZSW-UHVtRjIyUng0S1k/view?usp=sharing) 
when i try to reload the page when the internet connection is offline i cant access my page. i try to do fabio sugestion. and its give me 404 error.

Comment: Can you use Chrome DevTools to load the page with your service worker, go ti DevTools > application > service worker and double check it's actually registering the service worker. If it is then right click "caches" > "Refresh Caches" in the application tab and see if there are any caches and whether anything is cached.

Comment: Hi @GauntFace thank you so much for the answer. its working now i try to move my views directory to inside the public directory and cache '/views/home.hbs' and its work.. thank you so much.. and i try to audit my web use light house and its said that my web support offline access. but when i stop connection i cant access my web.. and im working on it right now. thank you so much.

Comment: I think that the problem could be that ".hbs" files are not like .html files. They are files where you put some logic in order to render an actual ".html" file, but that process is made server side.
Only after the server has rendered the actual ".html" it makes the response to the clinet request.
Actually, if you go to the aplication tab in the dev-Tools, you can download an actual HTML file.
My guess is that you could cache the file that was sent to the client, the file that was rendered, and not the file that contains the internal logic to populate with "handlebarsjs" expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, without the dots, and add a skipWaiting function to the installer. (BTW you are caching "styles.css" while in the tree I read "style.css")

```
var cacheName ='v2';
var filesToCache = [
'/',
'public/css/style.css',
'js/app.js',
'views/home.hbs',
];


self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    }).then(function() {
        return self.skipWaiting();
    })
  );
});
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call the .hbs the same way you would call them on your app router.

If you have in your router :

```
router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});
```

then in your service worker you can cache it like:

```
var filesToCache = [
'/home',
'css/styles.css',
'js/app.js',
];
```

And yes you mispelled 'style'. 
Hope that helps someone